# Cannot save the customer error magento

Tags: magento-enterprise

I’m having a strange issue when it comes to new customer registration. After filling out the sign up form I get a “Cannot save the customer.” error - however the account is created successfully and the record is stored in Magento.

I think this issue start when i changed welcome email. but i replaced welcome email with original one. but still this issue is not fixed.

Welcome email is not receiving to customer

I’ve scoured the forums and all I can find is that people have similar issues with Mailchimp but I’m not using that extension.

Has anyone got the solution ? Please help.

Comment: If you include the full text of the error message you're seeing (the string "cannot be saved" isn't used anywhere in Magento's core code) as well as the full context of how a user signs up (pages navigations to with URLs) it'll be more likely people can help you.  What you have here is a vague description of a general problem, likely due to some customization in your system.  Without the above information it will be unlikely people can help you.

Comment: this error message is showing "Cannot save the customer." customer detail is saving in database and but customer is not receiving welecome email.

Comment: If that's the exact error message it's not a part of Stock Magento, and it likely the results of a custom extension. Search your extensions for that exception string, then examine the code context around it to figure out why Magento threw that exception.

Comment: It is coming from \app\code\core\Mage\Customer\AccountController.php. function createPostAction()

code : catch (Exception $e) {
                $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost())
                    ->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot save the customer.'));
            }

Comment: I have the same problem but to me customer are not saved at all,..when they try to fill the form to create a new customer system say : Cannot save the customer.

Answer (score 7):

Magento's core system code, or an observer, throws an exception somewhere in the customer saving code. It's cause up in this code block

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost())
        ->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot save the customer.'));
}
```

Magento will typically mask raw PHP error with plain text messages to avoid showing raw error messages to system users.  If I was you I'd temporarily edit the above to read

```
>addException($e, $this->__('Cannot save the customer.' . $e->getMessage()));
```

This will print out the entire error message.  Also, `var_dump($e)` should reveal the file/line number where the exception was thrown.  This will shed some light on what's happening in your system, and allow you to fix it.

Comment: i saw the error in exception.log file. error is "SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://121.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/xxxx?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://121.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/xxxx?wsdl". Do you know anything about this ? Please help.